# How to interpret binary data as integer in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm saving ip addresses as strings using php's `inet_pton` as a four byte string. To create a human readable representation using mysql I want to use [`inet_ntoa`<sup>*MySQL*</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa), however, it appears to only accept integer values.

So, how do I read a string like `!"#` (corresponding to ip `32.33.34.35`, also notice the space) as an integer (corresponding to `539042339` in this example)?

Comment: Why are you storing it as a four byte string instead of in a four byte int field as recommended?

Comment: I deleted my answer, I don't get it, can you display more what you have and what do you expect?

Comment: @Umbrella Because mysql 5.6 will use varbinary(16) to store ip addresses. I want to make to make the transition easy.

Comment: @jcho360 In case of a ipv4 address what happens is that each byte is interpreted as a char, and concatenated as a string. I want to go from string to integer (eg. 255.255.255.255 -> string ->  4294967295 -> inet_ntoa()).

Comment: @McEnroe I got that, but why did you say `how do I read a string like !"#`?

Comment: @jcho360 I want to interpret data that is saved in form of a string which looks like ' !"#' (if it was to be printed) and have that converted to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something `Hex()` to convert the string to hexadecimal, then `Conv()` to convert it to base 10.

`SELECT inet_ntoa(conv(hex(' !"#'), 16, 10))`

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL < 5.6.3, you can do this with a combination of `SUBSTR()` and `ORD()`:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(
    ORD(SUBSTR(' !"#', 1, 1)) * 16777216 +
    ORD(SUBSTR(' !"#', 2, 1)) * 65536 +
    ORD(SUBSTR(' !"#', 3, 1)) * 256 +
    ORD(SUBSTR(' !"#', 4, 1)))
```

Which results in:

```
32.33.34.35
```

Also, since you're practically there already, you could just create the string yourself with `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    ORD(SUBSTR(' !"#', 1, 1)), '.',
    ORD(SUBSTR(' !"#', 2, 1)), '.',
    ORD(SUBSTR(' !"#', 3, 1)), '.',
    ORD(SUBSTR(' !"#', 4, 1)))
```

I hope you're using VARCHAR (as opposed to CHAR) with MySQL 5+ or a binary column so you don't lose your trailing spaces.

To support IPv6, you'll need to check the length first with an `IF` statement and concatenate a little differently.

With MySQL 5.6.3, the new `INET6_NTOA()` function supports this directly. It takes in a binary string and supports both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
SELECT INET6_NTOA(' !"#')
```

Comment: I'm using varbinary. Would that a problem? Also, I will be storing ipv6 addresses in there. Is there a way to convert both/either to integers without `if`s?

Comment: @McEnroe, VARBINARY is a binary column, so you'll be fine with trailing spaces. It seems like MySQL's INET_NTOA() function only supports IPv4, so you may as well just create the string yourself. In the above solution, it might have been easier just to concatenate the ordinal values with '.' rather than use INET_NTOA(). I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: @McEnroe, I updated my answer regarding MySQL 5.6.3's new `INET6_NTOA()` function, which supports this perfectly.